# Knockout sort method doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, comparison, browser

I have an application which creates and manages activities. I use Knockout.js to hold activities in observable array. Whenever new activity is created it is inserted into an array. One of the activity properties is date. I want to order activities by date after creating new one, to display it properly in UI. This is a function I use for it:

```
self.Activities.unshift(activity);
self.Activities.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dateA = new Date(a.date() + " 00:00:00");
    var dateB = new Date(b.date() + " 00:00:00");
    return dateA > dateB;
});
```

And it works perfectly in Firefox (v 16.0.2) but doesn't work in Chrome (v 23.0.1...), Safari or IE

Why? What is the workaround? If any?

Comment: 1. Switch your copy of knockout.js to the debug version found here: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js
2. Tell us what the console says in chrome when you get the error.

Comment: Can you please define "doesn't work". Also how you set the `date` on `Activity`? Because it should work fine in chrome also if you handle your dates correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/emBqv/3/

Comment: I have switched knockout to debug version, but no error appears in javascript console; a.date() or b.date() both return strings in this format: 4/12/2012

Comment: nemesv - I looked at the  jsfiddle.net/nemesv/emBqv/3 and it looks like that the date format is causing an issue. For some reason chrome doesn't like d/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comparer function that you pass needs to `sort` needs to return a number.  Some browsers are forgiving and work with a boolean.

Generally you would return -1 or 1.  Something like:

```
return dateA > dateB ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: The problem actually lies in the fact that Chrome doesnt like my String to Date conversion ("Invalid Date"). I use "4/12/2012" format for my dates

Comment: You will still need to return a number for sorting to work properly in Safari and others.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a wrong Date format. For some reason Chrome doesn't like: d/MM/yyyy, when I used yyyy/MM/d everything works fine